# Every $k$-critical graph has a $k-1$-critical subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I want to prove that any given $k$ ($k \geq 2$) critical graph $G$ has a $(k-1)$ critical subgraph. A graph is critical if any subgraph $H \subset G$ accepts a $k-1$ coloring, or in other terms, it has a chromatic number less than $k$.

I tried doing it by contradiction, assuming that a graph $G$ is $k$ critical but has no $k-1$ critical subgraphs. That is, any subgraph accepts a $k-2$ coloring, but $G$ has $\chi(G) = k$. I don't know where to go from here. I also thought of doing it by induction on $k$, since for $k = 2,3$, it is obvious. Then I assume I have my property for $k$, now I want to see what happens in $k+1$, but I don't know how to use my hypothesis.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will note. If any subgraph of a graph $G$ admits a properly coloring in $k-2>0$ colors, then $\chi(G)\leq k-1$.

Answer (score 1):

You know that removing an edge from a graph does not lower the chromatic number by more than $1$; and removing an isolated vertex (assuming the graph had more than one vertex to start with!) does not change the chromatic number at all.

You can assume $k\ge3$ since the case $k=2$ is obvious. Your graph $G$ is $k$-critical, so in particular it's not $(k-2)$-colorable.

If you can remove some edge without making the graph $(k-2)$-colorable, pick such an edge and remove it. Repeat this step until you can no longer remove an edge without making the graph $(k-2)$-colorable.

Finally, if there are any isolated vertices, remove them. You can show that the graph you're left with is $(k-1)$-critical.

Comment: I see. So I then end up with a graph that can't be $k$ colorable, but by construction is not $k-2$ colorable (can I assume it is not $k-3$,$k-4$, etc colorable?). So it has to be $k-1$ colorable, in particular $k-1$ chromatic, and then use the theorem that states that any $k$ chromatic graph has a $k$ critical subgraph?

Comment: Huh? Once you've got a graph which is not $(k-2)$-colorable, but you can't remove any edge (or vertex) without making it $(k-2)$-colorable, then the graph is already $(k-1)$-critical, so you don't have to use any theorem.

Comment: Oh, I see. Guess I was just overengineering the solution. Thanks for the clarification.